# Can std::lock_guard be interupted?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, locking

If I have some code under lock_guard like:

```
std::thread t([&]()
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m);
    // some simple operations
});
```

Do I have a guarantee that "some operations" will never be interrupted on this core cpu that `t` thread is running? Can there be context switching after lock_guard?

Comment: What is your idea of thread and mutex?

Comment: Your *program* does not interrupt the operations.

Comment: @Biagio Festa. Do you ask me? OK, I will answer... This construction guarantees that there won't be race condition during "some simple operations" but I wonder if the thread is blocked (I mean, operations are executed without interruption on this cpu core - without context switching)

Answer (score 1):

There will be context switches but it is guaranteed that all other threads will be blocked behind the lock.

Answer (score 0):

No, a critical section protected by a mutex is not going to run with *real-time priority* unless you explicitly request it to do so, which cannot be done using the standard C++ library. The kernel can still schedule another thread (in the same process, or some other process) that isn't waiting on the mutex. Setting real-time priority can only be done with OS-specific system calls.